# Query for state attributes

Tags: corda

If I have a state with an attribute, e.g.:

```
class Test(val timestamp: Double, val linearId = UniqueIdentifier()): LinearState
```

I can execute a vault query based on the linearId with `LinearStateQueryCriteria`. Is there a way to define query criteria for the attributes of a State? For example, get every state where the timestamp attribute is equal to `x` or even in a range between `y` and `z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work if your State is a QueryableState. You could use a `VaultCustomQueryCriteria` to get the desired result as shown below:

```
QueryCriteria generalCriteria = new VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.ALL);

FieldInfo attributeCurrency = getField("currency", CashSchemaV1.PersistentCashState.class);
FieldInfo attributeQuantity = getField("pennies", CashSchemaV1.PersistentCashState.class);

CriteriaExpression currencyIndex = Builder.equal(attributeCurrency, "USD");
CriteriaExpression quantityIndex = Builder.greaterThanOrEqual(attributeQuantity, 10L);

QueryCriteria customCriteria2 = new VaultCustomQueryCriteria(quantityIndex);
QueryCriteria customCriteria1 = new VaultCustomQueryCriteria(currencyIndex);


QueryCriteria criteria = generalCriteria.and(customCriteria1).and(customCriteria2);
Vault.Page<ContractState> results = vaultService.queryBy(Cash.State.class, criteria);
```

Refer here for more details: https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html

Refer here if you want to learn about QueryableState:
https://medium.com/corda/persisting-corda-states-in-custom-database-tables-using-queryablestate-dedaa18b7050